# Using Excel's UpdateLink() method from VBScript

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I want to update all the links in a certain Excel file and I put the code on a VBScript. What is wrong with the following code?

```
file = Directory2 & Filename2
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(file)
objExcel.Application.Visible = True
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:=ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources 
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save 
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

This returns:

> Error code: 800A0400

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VBScript doesn't support named parameters (`Name:=ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources`)

`Name` is the first argument to `UpdateLink()`, however, so just pass the value:

```
objWorkbook.UpdateLink objWorkbook.LinkSources
```

You were also using `ActiveWorkbook` without qualifying it. You need to use either:

```
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources
```

or

```
objWorkbook.LinkSources
```