# Using Excels LinkSources in VBScript

Tags: excel, vbscript, hyperlink

I am using basic VBScript to open an Excel workbook and update the links in it to another Excel workbook. If I open the file manually, I can update the links readily.  However, if the same Excel workbook is opened via VBScript there is an odd situation where the links cannot find the source file.  The two files are in different folders, but under the same parent folder on a network drive.

This is so simple a need, yet I'm at a loss. For some reason when I open the file in VBS the path to the links 'gets lost'.  I have a similar process where the file and its linked file sit in same folder and I can process that.  In this case I really can't move files just to work around this issue.

Current command is simply:

```vb
ObjExcel.ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources
```

Links work in same workbook manually.  If I open the workbook via VBScript with it visible but if I sleep the script to manually update the links in the open workbook I am told source not found.

Update:  quite a while back I tried:

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink ()

but I receive the error that the Update Method of WorkBook class failed.  I tried this again today.

I am sure the issue has to do with the source and destination files are in slightly different network folders.  I can open the same file manually and update links fine.  If I open the workbook via VBS, pause the script, and manually try to update links in that same file I get and error of source not found.  I close the script, manually opens same file, and links update fine.

Comment: Pure guess but try adding 2 `DoEvents` after opening and before calling linksources (yes, I do mean 2)

Comment: Do you not need to call `UpdateLink()`? - See [Using Excel's UpdateLink() method from VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31613446)

Comment: I used that same article about UpdateLink() to find the current approach.  Although the update does not work (source file not found), there are no errors thrown.  I receive an error using UpdateLink() of Update Method of WorkBook class failed

Comment: I am sure the issue is something about the source and destination workbooks for the links existing in slightly different network paths,  In non-technical terms, the path to the links arent found if triggered in VBS

Comment: I am unsure of the suggestion on DoEvents.